# Sharing ArcMap project?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, map-package

I am new to GIS. I would like to share a ArcMap project that I initiated with someone else.

Is there a way to share directly this project with the data, to allow the person to keep working on it?

[image]

Comment: Do you both have access to the same network drive?

Answer (score 1):

You want to "Package Map". This will bundle up all the layers into a single file you can send someone and they can then open that and work on it, essentially from the same state you left it when you made the package.
There is both a Geoprocessing Tool and from the File Menu > Share as > Map Package option.

You can read more about it in the Help page on [Creating a map package](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/creating-a-map-package.htm).